# Definition of r-shift in book A first look at rigorous probability theory (page 3)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am struggling to understand the following from page 3 of book *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory* by Jeffrey S. Rosenthal. The author says following:

For each subset $A \subseteq [0,1]$, we define the r-shift of A by

$A \oplus r \equiv \{a + r; a \in A, a + r \leqslant 1 \} \cup \{a + r - 1; a \in A, a + r > 1\}$,

then  we  should  have

$P(A \oplus r) = P(A),    0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1.$

In above statement by author, I fail to understand how $0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1$, because I can set, $r = 1000$ or $r = -1000$, and the definition of $A \oplus r$ still holds.

Please let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: If $r < 0$ or $r > 1$, then $A \oplus r$ (as defined here) won't be a subset of $[0,1]$. Of course one can modify the definition to work for all real $r$, but presumably this is not needed for the argument being made by the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of $r$-shift is to shift $A$ by an amount of $r$ over the interval $[0,1)$ *thought of cyclically*. For general $r$, the definition would be $A \oplus r = \{a + r \pmod{1} : a \in A\}$, where $x \pmod{1}$ is the unique $t \in [0,1)$ such that $x-t$ is an integer.

As Bungo mentions, presumably $P$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and so the claim is actually false if $r \notin [0,1]$: the measure of $A \oplus r$ could drop as parts of $A$ could go out of bounds.